# How can I use PyMOL API from Python?

Tags: python, pymol

I have PyMOL already installed on my Linux machine. I know it is installed because when I write `pymol -cp pymol_api_test.py` the script executes.

I want to run the following python script using `python3`:

```
import pymol
from pymol import cmd

print(cmd.align("/home/bbq_spatial/bbq_input_pdb/pdb1a6j.pdb",  
                "/home/bbq_spatial/bbq_output_pdb/pdb1a6j.pdb", 
                cycles=0, transform=0))
```

However, it doesn't run when I call it using `python3`:

```
user_name@server_name:~$ nano pymol_api_test.py
user_name@server_name:~$ python3 pymol_api_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymol_api_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymol'
user_name@server_name:~$
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you install it?

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: ok, but how? where? how do you know it's installed?

Answer (score 0):

Install `conda` (or `pip`) as a package manger for Python.
And then install `pymol` with the following commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c schrodinger pymol-bundle
```

You can check your installed packages in your env with the following command:

```
conda list
```

Use [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html) link to install conda on your Linux machine.

Pay attention,`PyMol` may require other dependencies on you system, check the official guides for installation.

UPDATE:

Check a specific pkg:

with pip: `pip show <pkg>`

with conda: `conda show <pkg>`

List all installed pkgs:

with pip: `pip list`

with conda: `conda list`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Besides, why should I install pymol again?

Comment: Make sure it's installed in your runtime environment.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Use you package manager. Check the update in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean `pymol` by `<pkg>`?

Comment: Not sure, the name of the package may differ. But you can check the list.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your python interpreter has access to the `pymol` package. This can be done adding it to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

```bash
$ export PYTHONPATH=/opt/pymol/lib/python3.10/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
```

In linux, the `pymol` command is not a binary but just a shell script to run the corresponding python package. So you can check it to get the correct path to be added.

```bash
$ cat $(which pymol)

#!/bin/sh
exec "/usr/bin/python3" "/opt/pymol/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymol/__init__.py" "$@"
```